# Refactoring Lists

Tags: list, scheme

I'm looking to take in a list with strings and numbers, such as

```
'("Ben" 95 99 100 -1 "Bob" 90 40 66 -5 "Jerry" 95 90 0)
```

and return the list with all negative numbers removed and the name and its subsequent number values place inside of a list within that list - for my example, the wanted return value would be

```
(("Ben 95 99 100) ("Bob" 90 40 66) ("Jerry" 95 90 0))
```

I can't get it to place the parentheses in the right places, and I'm wondering how this can be done. Can anyone help?

Comment: It would certainly help if you could provide some detail on how you're actually going about this problem. Code snippets are helpful, or at least the language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (refactor lst acc)
  (cond ((empty? lst) (list acc))
        ((and (number? (first lst)) (< (first lst) 0))
         (cons acc (refactor (rest lst) '())))
        (else (refactor (rest lst) (append acc (list (first lst)))))))
```

When tested with the sample input provided:

```
(define lst '("Ben" 95 99 100 -1 "Bob" 90 40 66 -5 "Jerry" 95 90 0))
(refactor lst '())
```

The returned value is as expected:

```
(("Ben" 95 99 100) ("Bob" 90 40 66) ("Jerry" 95 90 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pity I can't comment on Oscar's answer. It separates the list by the negative numbers instead of the strings, so it leads to error as below (Tested in Petite Chez Scheme, replacing first->car, rest->cdr, empty?->null? in case I misunderstand the keywords):

```
> (refactor '("Ben" 95 99 100 -1 "Bob" 90 -7 40 66 -5 "Jerry" 95 -5 90 0) '())
(("Ben" 95 99 100) ("Bob" 90) (40 66) ("Jerry" 95) (90 0))
```

Here's one solution. acc is the current sublist which starts with the last word, following with non-negative numbers before touching the next word.

```
(define (refactor lst acc)
   (cond ((null? lst) (list acc))
         ((and (not (number? (car lst))) (null? acc))
          (refactor (cdr lst) (list (car lst))))
         ((and (not (number? (car lst))) (not (null? acc)))
          (cons acc (refactor (cdr lst) (list (car lst)))))
         ((and (number? (car lst)) (< (car lst) 0)
          (refactor (cdr lst) acc)))
         (else (refactor (cdr lst) (append acc (list (car lst)))))))
```

Tested as below:

```
> (refactor '("Ben" 95 99 100 -1 "Bob" 90 -7 40 66 -5 "Jerry" 95 -5 90 0) '())
(("Ben" 95 99 100) ("Bob" 90 40 66) ("Jerry" 95 90 0))
> (refactor '("Ben" 95 99 100 -1 "Bob" 90 40 66 -5 "Jerry" 95 90 0) '())
(("Ben" 95 99 100) ("Bob" 90 40 66) ("Jerry" 95 90 0))
> (refactor '("Ben" 95 99 100 -1 "Bob" "Jerry" 95 90 0) '())
(("Ben" 95 99 100) ("Bob") ("Jerry" 95 90 0))
> (refactor '(-10 "Ben" -1 "Bob" -5 "Jerry" 0) '())
(("Ben") ("Bob") ("Jerry" 0))
```

Comment: I think this works just fine as an answer, rather than a comment. It's far too much information for a comment!